# Remote bash script execution via ssh causes local script to stop

Tags: ssh, bash, scripting, dd

I have a setup which behaves in a way i cannot get my head around. 
So I have a local bash script `generateTrafficOnHosts.sh` which reads IP addresses from a file. It then calls a bash script `getTraffic.sh` on each remote host, i.e. each IP address it calls.
However, after the first remote execution via ssh, it just finishes. Here's my local `generateTrafficOnHosts.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Connects to a series of hosts and runs the get-traffic.sh script on     them. 
# The hosts are taken from a file with a list of randomly generated IDs,
# while their IDs are taken from a connectfile.

# ...
# some convenience functions here
# ...

#######################################
# runs the traffic generation script on
# a host.
# Globals:
#   
# Arguments:
#   <IP of the remote host>
# Returns:
#   None
#######################################
function run_on_host() {
    local RESULTS
    RESULTS=$(ssh -i key.pem user@"$1" '/home/user/get-traffic.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null')
}

#######################################
# Runs the load on the hosts
# Globals:
#   HOSTSFILE
# Arguments:
#   None
# Returns:
#   None
#######################################
function run_load_on_hosts() {
    while read line
    do
        local ip=$(get_ip_for_key ${line})
        echo "getting IP for key in line ${line}"
        if [[ $ip != "" ]]; then
            echo "running on host $line($ip)"
            run_on_host "${ip}"
        else
            echo "error: LINE'$line', IP'$ip'"
        fi
    done < "$HOSTSFILE"
}

function main() {
    check "$@"
    run_load_on_hosts
}

main "$@"
```

The remote script `get-traffic.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PORT=47111

# Time limit in seconds
TIME_LIMIT=10
# Blocksize of the dd command: how much data shall be downloaded per chunk? 
BS=1M

while [[ "$SECONDS" -le "$TIME_LIMIT" ]]; do
    # $SECONDS is a shell variable
    nc "${HOST}" "${PORT}" | dd count=1 bs="${BS}" iflag=fullblock > /dev/null
done
```

Now for the odd behaviour: the script only runs for the first host in the hosts file. If I replace the line `ssh -i ...` with, say, `sleep 1; echo "running..."`, everything runs smoothly. The same applies if I replace the remote command `/home/user/get-traffic.sh` with e.g. `ls /home/user` - everything is good. However, the script also returns after the first iteration if I replace the remote command with `ls`.

I have been tracking this bug for hours now, and I have run out of ideas hours ago. Anyone, please?!? :|

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `ssh` manual, more specificaly the `-t` option.

If this doesn't work, try the `-tt` option. Also, I think your `get-traffic.sh` script should `exit 0` at the end.

Comment: hm, both options unfortunately don't change a thing :(

Comment: BUT you pointed me somehow in the right direction. Allocating a pseudo-terminal is not needed, since my script always has one attached. However, the remote script needed some stdin - hence using `-n` did the trick. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote you since I have a new account here. But cheers!